# Adding a template directory to the template directory

Tags: directory, templates

Ubuntu has a templates directory in the home directory. Files can be added to it, and they're added to Gnome's context menu, easily accessible for created new files from the template. And if you add new directories, they give the context menu more levels, allowing for convenient organization.

However, this latter feature creates a problem if I'm trying to create a template of a directory. I make a lot of small websites, and want to, with a quick right-click, create a folder that contains everything I need to start up a quick test website, such as dockerfiles, initial scripts, generic config files, etc.

I've tried putting together a zip file that I can then extract on location, but that's more steps not only for putting a tempalte somewhere, but also a lot more steps to update my template. Is there a way to have an easy context menu item that creates a copy of a directory at location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd better write a script that create your directory structure
Adapt the script for Nautilus
Put the script in the Nautilus script folder `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts` make it executable and browse a first time to the scripts folder with Nautilus.
Find more information about Nautilus scripts : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto

Sample script matching your need

```
#!/bin/bash
# Get Working Dir
if [ "$1" = "" ];then
    wdir=${NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI#file://}
    wdir=${wdir//%20/ }
else
    filetype=$(file "$1")
    filetype=${filetype##*: }

    if [ "$filetype" = "directory" ];then
        wdir=${NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS%%$1*}
        wdir=$wdir/$1
    else
        wdir=${NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS%%$1*}
    fi
fi

# Create file structure
mkdir '${wdir}/mydir'
touch '${wdir}/mydir/myfile'
```

Comment: That's an option that can work. I'll probably change some of the touches into cps though, so I don't have to repopulate the file contents, but otherwise, works for what I need! Thanks!